# While function python

Tags: python, eclipse, while-loop, pydev

Hello is use eclipse and pydev, I was wondering why my sample code won't work trying to use the while function.

```
print("Welcome to the annoying program")
response = ""
while response != "Because.":
  response = input("why\n")

print("Oh,ok")
```

the output is the following:

```
Welcome to the annoying program
why
Because.
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "/Users/calebmatthias/Document/workspace/de.vogella.python.first/simpprogram.py", l      ine 9, in <module>
   response = input("why\n")
File "/Users/calebmatthias/Desktop/eclipse     2/plugins/org.python.pydev_2.2.3.2011100616/PySrc/pydev_sitecustomize/sitecustomize.py", line 210, in input
return eval(raw_input(prompt))
File "<string>", line 1
Because.
       ^
SyntaxError: unexpected EOF while parsing
```

Comment: It looks like you're mixing up code from Python 2.X and Python 3.X. Which version are you scripting this code for?

Comment: Please fix your code formatting and make sure it reflects exactly what you have. Whitespace is important in Python.

Answer (score 6):

The `input` function in 2.x evaluates the input as Python code!  Use the `raw_input` function instead.

With `input`, your text "Because." is being evaluated, and it's a syntax error because the dot isn't followed by anything.

Comment: This is true, but it doesn't really explain the reported error.

Comment: @Kbob1998: You can accept the answer if you like it.  Also, I note that this answer is exactly the one you got to your previous question: make use of them, it will save you time!

Comment: Thx for the tip. The stack overflow community are very good to the newbies like myself